# "She'll be sleeping in my tower." Why the future continuous?

Tags: future-tense, future-continuous

This dialogue is from a series called “A discovery of witches”.

The male protagonist, a vampire, is talking to her mom about the sleeping arrangements for his girlfriend, a witch, who is being pursued by dangerous people but has found safety in his boyfriend castle (of course he has a castle). Witches and vampires have never gotten along with each other, so his mother has a little bit of resentment towards this woman but she’s trying not to show it, for the sake of her son.

She says:

> She needs some rest, it’s been a long journey. I’ll make up her room.

And his son replies:

> No, I’ll do it. **She’ll be sleeping** in my tower.

Now, why does the vampire use the future continuous? Why not the future simple? Would it have a different meaning? Are they interchangeable? If so, why use one over the other?

Comment: _She'll be sleeping_ implies that this will be a regular sleeping place for her. _She'll sleep_ doesn't exclude that, but it doesn't imply it either.

Comment: "The **male** ... is talking to **his** mom ... " In English the possessive pronoun takes the gender of the possessor not the thing possessed.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this Grammarly article](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/future-continuous-tense/), the difference between `future simple` and `future continuous` could be a matter of how long the verb will take place:

> Will be meeting is the future continuous tense of the verb to meet. The construction will + be + the present participle meeting indicates that the meeting isn’t going to happen in an instant, all at once. It will have a duration. The will + be + present participle construction always indicates the future continuous tense. **Example: Michael will be running a marathon this Saturday.**

So, because the act of `sleeping` doesn't occur instantly, and instead takes probably 6-8 hours to do, it is fair to use the future continuous `She'll be sleeping in my tower.` instead of the future simple `She'll sleep in my tower.`

However, if you ask most native speakers, I'm sure that the vast majority would agree that both `She'll be sleeping in my tower` and also `She'll sleep in my tower` communicate the exact same information, and both sound equally correct for this situation.